extract audio from react-native-webrtc and save into audio file
I am using 'react-native-webrtc' for video calling between 2 people and I want to save the audio to get the transcription text, how do I do that?
I have setup the video call functionality and there was an issue that audio was not coming from Spearker but from earphones so I am using react-native-incall-manager to get the audio from the speaker.
import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';
can we extract the audio from webrtc stream data?
i tried native kotlin code but did not work
     audioRecord =
            AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
                sampleRate,
                channelConfig,
                audioFormat,
                bufferSize
            )
        audioRecord?.startRecording()

but becuase of this audio is not going to receiver.
and tried other recorder like react-native-audio-recorder-player but audio is not going to other end.
